# Does MTB tyres wear off fast in City - gravel pavement streets, city road?

Tags: road-bike, mountain-bike, off-road

I want to buy a Cross country MTB that I want to use everyday to work within the city in weekdays. In weekends I want to take it for off-city roads with partially mud and grassy terrain.

Will the MTB tyres wear off fast when using the city?

Comment: If possible a second wheel set would be ideal, one mounted with off-road tires, the second with city tires. Swapping wheels is a fairly easy. Changing tires all the time is a pain.

Comment: I doubt that they'd wear any faster, overall, than when used off-road, but the wear pattern would be different -- more in the center.  And in any event you're talking 1000-3000 miles to a set.  The bigger consideration is that off-road tires slow you down on smooth pavement.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Not.  I went though CX tires commuting on my CX every 6 months and I get 3 years on touring tires.   Wear down the middle wears them out.

Comment: Tyres are consumable items - use up the ones it comes with and then buy new tyres.

Comment: @Paparazzi - And same width and air pressure for both?

Comment: @SheikhFaisalMiskhat - if you have disc brakes you may need to shim the rotors so that you don't get brake rub when you swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they wear faster on the road than road tires and do not get as good of traction especially wet.

You can get hardpack tires that are more solid in the middle but they are not going to be good on mud and wet grass.  Mountain on dry days with touring tires or hardpack is a better combo.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, absolutely. The knobs will get rounded off at an accelerated rate, particularly down the center of the rear tire, and the tires won't offer as much traction off-road. This doesn't happen instantly, but it will happen soon enough on a knobby used for primarily road riding.

Comment: sounds legitimate.